Odoo is keeping loading an overridden field as defined from the core
In one of my customizations, I have a field ProjectProject.company_id as not required, but for some reason when Odoo is upgrading modules, it loads the core module Project and set the value again (default).
After upgrade the field is kept as not required (my customization takes effect).
It seems that my customization is not taking effect when Odoo loads the core module Project.

I found that Odoo loads the core module, consider the field as required, it detect some records has no value then fill with the default value. This happens before my custom module is loaded, so nothing I can do, except monkeypatching.
I put this code on my custom module,
from odoo.addons.project.models.project import Project
Project.company_id.required = False

it gets loaded on python code compilation, so it does take effect when loading the core module
